# When training a RBM how should the data be normalised?

Tags: normalization, unsupervised-learning, restricted-boltzmann-machine

A feed forward neural network trains best if the data is normalised so that each input has a mean of 0 and a standard deviation of 1.
Is this true for a Restricted Boltzmann machine as well?
(My experiments are saying, no it isn't.)

Comment: Based on my experience and some papers if you are working on binary RBM you should normalize your data between [0,1]. could you explain why your experiment says no?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That depends on the distributions you assume the visible and hidden variables to have. If the visibles are binary, you should scale them to the [0, 1] interval. If they are Gaussian, you should scale them to $\mathcal{N}(0, 1)$.